# UWP How can I change the cursor for a custom one?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mouse-cursor

If I have a .cur file which I want to use as a custom cursor in my UWP application, how would I do that?

Also, do cursors need to be black and white or can they have colour?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a CoreCursor of type CoreCursorType.Custom and specifying the resource ID of your custom cursor file. Documentation is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor

Comment: Thanks, I had read that, but I can't really understand how to make the .res file, or if I  need it in the first place